# On the uniqueness of Wannier functions

Tags: condensed-matter, wavefunction, fourier-transform, electronic-band-theory

Was reading this text 'Electronic structure : basic theory and practical methods' by Richard.M.Martin and came across this following line: 'The most serious drawback of the Wannier representation is that the functions are not uniquely defined. They can vary strongly in shape and range, as opposed to the Bloch
functions that are unique'.

Given that Wannier functions are simple fourier transforms of bloch functions, how do they differ in 'uniqueness' from bloch functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bloch functions $\psi_k(x)$ (for a given band) are only defined up to a phase, that is,
$$
\psi_k(x) \ \leftrightarrow\ e^{i\theta_k}\psi_k(x)
$$
describe the same Bloch function.  On the other hand, if you take the Fourier transform of the $\psi_k(x)$ to obtain the Wannier functions $\phi_n(x)$, those phases will make a big difference, and you will obtain different Wannier functions depending how (and how smooth) you choose this phase.  (Note that e.g. saying "choose all $\theta_k=0$" does not even make sense, since you have to start off by *defining* what $\theta_k=0$ means.)

On the other hand, once you have the Wannier functions, they are related as
$$
\phi_n(x) = \phi_0(x+na)\ ,
$$
that is to say, their phase relation is completely fixed (all there is left is a *global* joint phase), so there is no problem when Fourier transforming back.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail "since you have to start off by defining what =0 means." Why do you need to define $e^{i\theta_k}=1$ artificially, thank you very much

Comment: $\psi(x)$ is not well defined. It is an eigenvector of the Hamlitonian, which is only defined up to a phase. It all boils down how you fix this phase.

Comment: Thank you, is "how to fix this phase" essentially how to determine which WS primitive cell in the inverted space is the first Brillouin zone, which is random in this place